# Find friend of my friend mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

```
users(id, name) 
friend(friend1,friend2)
images(name, id)
imageliked(imageId,likedId)
```

I want to get the images liked by friend of my friend with two select.
Can anyone help me.....

Comment: specify relation between those tables

Comment: I can see images liked by my friend........

Comment: SELECT image FROM images LEFT JOIN imageliked ON images.id = imageliked.imageId LEFT JOIN friend ON
imageliked.likedId = friend.friend1 or imageliked.likedId = friend.friend2 LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = friend.friend1 OR users.id = friend.friend2 WHERE users.id = 2;

Comment: But I must find images liked by friend of my friend

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  i.*
FROM friend AS f 
INNER JOIN imageLiked AS il ON il.likedId IN(f.friend1, f.friend2)
INNER JOIN images     AS  i ON il.imageId = i.id
WHERE 2 IN(f.friend1, f.friend2); -- 2 is my id for example
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02363/1)

---

**Note that:** This will include those images liked by you, if you want to remove them, just add `AND il.likedId <> yourId` to the `WHERE` clause.

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02363/3)

---

### Update:

To get the images liked by friends of you and by friends of friends:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  i.*
FROM 
(
  SELECT f1.friend1 as friend
  FROM friend AS f1
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT friend1
    FROM friend
    WHERE friend2 = 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT friend2
    FROM friend
    WHERE friend1 = 2
  ) AS f2 ON f2.friend1 IN (f1.friend1, f1.friend2)
  UNION 
  SELECT f1.friend2
  FROM friend AS f1
  INNER JOIN
  (

    SELECT friend1
    FROM friend
    WHERE friend2 = 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT friend2
    FROM friend
    WHERE friend1 = 2
  ) AS f2 ON f2.friend1 IN (f1.friend1, f1.friend2)
)AS f 
INNER JOIN imageLiked AS il ON il.likedId = f.friend
INNER JOIN images     AS  i ON il.imageId = i.id
WHERE il.likedId <> 2;
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09110/19)

---

To get only images liked by friends of my friends:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  i.*
FROM 
(
  SELECT f1.friend2 AS friend
  FROM friend AS f1
  INNER JOIN
  (

    SELECT friend1
    FROM friend
    WHERE friend2 = 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT friend2
    FROM friend
    WHERE friend1 = 2
  ) AS f2 ON f2.friend1 IN (f1.friend1, f1.friend2)
)AS f 
INNER JOIN imageLiked AS il ON il.likedId = f.friend
INNER JOIN images     AS  i ON il.imageId = i.id
WHERE il.likedId <> 2;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09110/23)

Comment: @Jesy - You're welcome any time :), **Note that:** This will include those images liked by you, if you want to remove them, just add `AND il.likedId <> yourId` to the `WHERE` clause. See my edit.

Comment: Excuse me Mahmoud it look like this?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT i.image FROM friend AS f INNER JOIN imageLiked AS il ON il.likedId IN(f.friend1, f.friend2) INNER JOIN images AS i ON il.imageId = i.id WHERE 2 IN(f.friend1, f.friend2) AND il.likedId <> 2

Comment: ooo, excuse me Mahmoud I didn`t see it at all, thank you very very much   dear Mahmoud

Comment: @Jesy - So does it work fine? Try it on your data and if anything goes wrong don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: excuse me Mahmoud it does not return me images liked by friend of my friend, can you see it http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09110/1 ..... I wrote my query like that... thank you for advance

Comment: @Jesy see my edit, this will give you the images liked by friends of you as well as the friends of friends and exclude those liked by you, if you want yo include thos liked by you remove `WHERE il.likedId <> 2`. Is this right or do you want only the images liked by friends of friends not the images liked by friends?

Comment: and I must use only 2 select

Comment: @Jesy - See my edit, But This is only one `SELECT`. What do you mean by only two selects?

Comment: in that query I must use only two select

Comment: @Jesy - I don't know really, this is what I could do, Sorry mate :)

Comment: To my maind I must join users table and give users.id @my_id, and It will bring images liked by friend of my friend

Comment: SELECT image FROM images INNER JOIN imageliked ON images.id = imageliked.imageId LEFT JOIN friend ON imageliked.likedId IN (SELECT f.* FROM friend AS f JOIN friend AS f2 ON f.friend1 = f2.friend2 OR f.friend1 = f2.friend1 LEFT JOIN users ON f.friend1 = users.id OR f.friend2 = users.id WHERE users.id = 2) WHERE imageliked.likedId <> 2;

Comment: @Jesy - I fixed it [**here**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09110/29), but it didn't give the right results

Comment: What do you think about it? in my data it is don`t return anything also

Comment: Dear Mahmoud I change inner joins to Left join and it return right result, thank you very much you help me a lot